# MySQL precision in AVG function with filtering

Tags: mysql

MySQL precision in AVG function with filtering

How MySQL handle precision when filtering on aggregated fields?

For example, I have the following table definition

```sql
CREATE TABLE `test_values` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

With the following data:

```
id  group   value
1   A       1
2   A       2
3   A       3
4   A       4
5   A       0
6   A       0
```

**Problem:**

```sql
SELECT `group`, AVG(`value`) FROM test_values
```

yields

```
group   AVG(`value`)
A       1.66666667
```

no problem so far.

But when I add `AVG(value) >= 1.66666667` to `HAVING` clause will return nothing:

```sql
SELECT `group`, AVG(`value`) FROM test_values
HAVING AVG(`value`) >= 1.666667
```

```
group   AVG(`value`)
```

It was weird that MySQL told me the result was `1.666667` but the record was not returned when `1.666667` applied as a filter.

What is the problem?

Comment: The real value is `1.66666666666...` which is smaller than `1.666667`. You could round your value to the precision you like before comparing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is stated by [juergen d](https://stackoverflow.com/users/575376/juergen-d) clearly in his comments, the value you have seen in the output i.e. `1.66666667` is not actually the value handled by mysql internally. It is actually `1.66666666.......`.

So, one way is to round the AVG value at first and then compare. Try this:

```
SELECT `group`, ROUND(AVG(value), 2) AS AVG FROM test_values HAVING ROUND(AVG(value), 2) >= 1.67
```

Alternatively, you may want to use FORMAT in stead of ROUND in this particular case as well:

```
SELECT `group`, FORMAT(AVG(value), 2) AS AVG FROM test_values HAVING FORMAT(AVG(value), 2) >= 1.67
```

Comment: Thanks, I've found rounding the result manually would resolve this issue.